# How server should push some notification to the client in an efficient manner?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, signalr

If we have saved user's number in a cookie and we randomly get some offer on few numbers which we have to display to the users on our website asap, how could we achieve that?

For every page or API hit, we check in cache or database if offer exists on that number. If it does, we set response cookie with the offer details and offer expiry date. If the offer doesn't exist, we set response cookie as "no offer" with few hours expiry so that it retries to get the offer.

Should we go with this approach i.e. for every API/page hit, check for an offer in cache/database and set the cookie OR should we poll from the client at regular intervals to check this information?

How should such problems where server need to push some notification to the client can be solved in an efficient manner?

We need to solve this issue across clients i.e. android, ios and web?

Comment: If it is necessary to display it urgently to all users, consider Web Sockets, so you can push from the server. They are much more efficient than AJAX polling from the browser/app side.

Comment: @halfer I am reading more about signalr. Could you share some link if you have worked on similar issue

Comment: That's a very broad question. I'm using a single-threaded Web Socket  server for PHP called ReactPHP, but if you're using .net then you will need to run a search for "Web Socket server .net" to see how to do it. Or of course you can use a service like Pusher, if you want someone to maintain the infrastructure for you.